# $p,q \in[1,\infty]$ are conjugate. If $u$ is measurable in $E$ and satisfies $uv \in L^1(E) \space\space \forall v \in L^q(E)$, then $u \in L^p(E)$.

Tags: real-analysis

$p,q \in[1,\infty]$ are conjugate. If $u$ is measurable in a measurable set $E \subset \mathbb{R}^d$ and satisfies $uv \in L^1(E) \space\space \forall v \in L^q(E)$, then $u \in L^p(E)$.

I was told that Closed Graph Theorem is a key to solve this question but I did not figure out how to apply the theorem here.

Comment: You can prove that if $u$ is not in $L_p$ then there exists a $v \in L_q$ such that $uv$ is not in $L_1$.

Answer (score 0):

Define $T_n:L^{q} \to L^{1}$ by $T_nv=uvI_{E_n}$ where $E_n=\{x: |u(x)| \leq n,\|x\|\leq n\}$. It is easy to see that this is a continuous linear map.  By hypothesis $\sup_n\|T_nu\|_1<\infty$ for each fixed $u$. By Uniform Boundedness Principle there is a finite constant $C$ such that $\|T_nv\|_1\leq C  \|v\|_q$ for all $n$. Hence $\int |uv| \leq C  \|v\|_q$ for all $v \in L^{q}$. Take $v=|u|^{p-1}I_{E_n} s(u)$ $s(u)=1$ for $ u \geq 0$ and $0$ for $u <0$. take sup over $n$.You will see that $u \in L^{p}$.

Comment: I have a small question but I haven't found an answer on the internet for it, so I hope you can please help. I was wondering if $u_n$ converges to $u$ in $L^2$, then does $u_nv$ converge to $uv$ if $v$ is a measurable function?

Comment: @FareedAF If $v \in L^{\infty}$ then $u_n v \to uv$ in $L^{2}$. Without any assumption on $v$ the answer is NO.